# Heat capacity of calorimeter

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, heat, calorimetry, specific-heat

The problem is:

> $\pu{30 mL}$ of water at $\pu{24.00 °C}$ were stored in a calorimeter in a laboratory experiment. Then, $\pu{40 mL}$ of water at $\pu{55.00 °C}$ were added to the calorimeter achieving thermal equilibrium when temperature reached $\pu{40.00 °C}$ in the system. Subsequently, the same calorimeter is used to dissolve $\pu{6.42 g}$ of ammonium nitrate in $\pu{110.00 g}$ of water at $\pu{23.00 °C}$. This new system reaches the thermal equilibrium at $\pu{19.05 °C}$. The specific heat capacity of ammonium nitrate can be considered as $c_\mathrm{s} = \pu{1,6643 J/°C}$. Calculate $\Delta_\mathrm{sol}H$ of ammonium nitrate and heat capacity of calorimeter.

What I did is I calculated the heat of reaction
\begin{align}
  Q_\mathrm{rxn}
  &= mC_\ce{H2O}\Delta T \\
  &= (116.42)(4.18)(19.05 - 23) \\
\end{align}
and I also know that $\Delta_\mathrm{sol}H = Q_\mathrm{rxn} + q_\text{cal}$. However, how do we calculate the heat capacity of the calorimeter?

Comment: Formulate the equation with calorimeter capacity as the unknown variable and calculate it's value, leading to the final Tc r 40.00 Deg C.